# Регулярное выражение для парсинга данных между тегами

Tags: php, python, регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно с помощью скрипта на PHP или Python получить ТиЦ сайта. Смотрится он так: https://yaca.yandex.ua/yca/cy/ch/ru.stackoverflow.com . В этом случае все просто, дешево и удобно. Однако если сайт попадает в какую-нить статистику, все становиться намного сложнее: https://yaca.yandex.ua/yca/cy/ch/2ip.ru
Мне нужно получить ТиЦ именно во втором случае. Регулярку под это дело я так написать и не смог. Должно быть реализовано либо на Python, либо на PHP.

Comment: `https:\/\/yaca.yandex.ua[\/.\w]*` вполне работает для поиска. Хорошо бы иметь пример, откуда искать

Comment: Скорее всего я не правильно выразился. Уже есть целевой сайт, например,http://ru.stackoverflow.com/ . Что бы проверить его ТиЦ нужно пройти по ссылке https://yaca.yandex.ua/yca/cy/ch/ru.stackoverflow.com и спарсить цифру, в данном случае она 325. На такую задачу у меня есть решение, однако если сайт попадает в какую нибудь категорию, то все намного сложнее. Если посмотреть ТиЦ сайта 2ip.ru (https://yaca.yandex.ua/yca/cy/ch/2ip.ru) можно наблюдать целую категорию. Достать ТиЦ (4800) с таким выводом намного сложнее

Comment: проверьте предоставляет ли yandex API (например, чтобы в виде JSON получить необходимую вам информацию). В общем случае, используйте html-парсеры, чтобы изъять информацию из html, а не регулярные выражения -- обязательно для прочтения: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/4279).

Comment: @jfs: Это, кстати, очень похоже на классический пример [отсюда](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/795/10105)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример кода на *Python* для второго случая:

```
import urllib.request
import re

site_url = "2ip.ru"
base_url = "https://yaca.yandex.ua/yca/cy/ch/"

url = base_url + site_url
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf8')
html = html.replace('\n', '')
m = re.search("://" + site_url + ".*?<td>(\d+)</td>", html)
print("ТИЦ(" + site_url + ")=" + m.group(1))
```

А вот то же самое, но на *PHP*:

```
<?php
    $site_url = '2ip.ru';
    $base_url = 'https://yaca.yandex.ru/yca/cy/ch/';
    $html = file_get_contents($base_url . $site_url);
    $html = str_replace("\n", '', $html);
    preg_match("/:\/\/$site_url.*?<td>(\d+)<\/td>/", $html, $m);
    echo("ТИЦ($site_url)=$m[1]");
?>
```